Decoding Transaction Input Using ABI. Web3 py
I am correctly grabbing the ABI as I have confirmed it is the same on etherscan. I am also getting the transaction[input].hex() correctly which displays the hex of the input I am trying to decode. Can anyone help me fix my function? I am trying to decode the input of a transaction I know the hash of. Basically what this website is doing but just locally on my computer using the Web3 py library: https://lab.miguelmota.com/ethereum-input-data-decoder/example/
Here is my function to fix:
def decode(input_data, abi):
    print("Decoding input data: ", input_data)
    print("Using ABI: ", abi)
    input_bytes = bytes.fromhex(input_data[2:])  # Convert input_data to bytes, skipping '0x'
    for item in abi:
        if item['type'] == 'function':
            signature = item['name'] + '('
            for i in range(len(item['inputs'])):
                signature += item['inputs'][i]['type']
                if i != len(item['inputs']) - 1:
                    signature += ','
            signature += ')'
            
            signature_hash = Web3.keccak(text=signature).hex()

            # Remove '0x' prefix when converting to bytes
            signature_bytes = bytes.fromhex(signature_hash[2:])

            # not getting past this point
            # print("Signature Bytes: ", signature_bytes)
            # print("Input Bytes: ", input_bytes)

            if input_bytes.startswith(signature_bytes):
                print(f"Function: {item['name']}")
                print(f"Inputs: {item['inputs']}")
                print(f"Outputs: {item['outputs']}")
                print(f"Method ID: {signature_hash[:10]}")
                print(f"Input Data: {input_data}")
                break

Here is the current output:
Decoding input data:  0x845d76f7000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000020243aff03840e7bf14bd53b7c18015018be4b3c000000000000000000000000c02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2
Using ABI:  [{'inputs': [], 'stateMutability': 'payable', 'type': 'constructor'}, {'anonymous': False, 'inputs': [{'indexed': True, 'internalType': 'address', 'name': 'owner', 'type': 
'address'}, {'indexed': True, 'internalType': 'address', 'name': 'spender', 'type': 'address'}, {'indexed': False, 'internalType': 'uint256', 'name': 'value', 'type': 'uint256'}], 'name': 'Approval', 'type': 'event'}, {'anonymous': False, 'inputs': [{'indexed': False, 'internalType': 'uint256', 'name': '_maxTxAmount', 'type': 'uint256'}], 'name': 'MaxTxAmountUpdated', 'type': 'event'}, {'anonymous': False, 'inputs': [{'indexed': True, 'internalType': 'address', 'name': 'previousOwner', 'type': 'address'}, {'indexed': True, 'internalType': 'address', 'name': 'newOwner', 'type': 'address'}], 'name': 'OwnershipTransferred', 'type': 'event'}, {'anonymous': False, 'inputs': [{'indexed': True, 'internalType': 'address', 'name': 'from', 'type': 'address'}, {'indexed': True, 'internalType': 'address', 'name': 'to', 'type': 'address'}, {'indexed': False, 'internalType': 'uint256', 'name': 'value', 'type': 'uint256'}], 'name': 'Transfer', 'type': 'event'}, {'inputs': [], 'name': '_maxTaxSwap', 'outputs': [{'internalType': 'uint256', 'name': '', 'type': 'uint256'}], 'stateMutability': 'view', 'type': 'function'}, {'inputs': [], 'name': '_maxTxAmount', 'outputs': [{'internalType': 'uint256', 'name': '', 'type': 'uint256'}], 'stateMutability': 'view', 'type': 'function'}, {'inputs': [], 'name': '_maxWalletSize', 'outputs': [{'internalType': 'uint256', 'name': '', 'type': 'uint256'}], 'stateMutability': 'view', 'type': 'function'}, {'inputs': [], 'name': '_taxSwapThreshold', 'outputs': [{'internalType': 'uint256', 'name': '', 'type': 'uint256'}], 'stateMutability': 'view', 'type': 'function'}, {'inputs': [{'internalType': 'address[]', 'name': 'bots_', 'type': 'address[]'}], 'name': 'addBots', 'outputs': [], 'stateMutability': 'nonpayable', 'type': 'function'}, {'inputs': [{'internalType': 'address', 'name': 'owner', 'type': 'address'}, {'internalType': 'address', 'name': 'spender', 'type': 'address'}], 'name': 'allowance', 'outputs': [{'internalType': 'uint256', 'name': '', 'type': 'uint256'}], 'stateMutability': 'view', 'type': 'function'}, {'inputs': [{'internalType': 'address', 'name': 'spender', 'type': 'address'}, {'internalType': 'uint256', 'name': 'amount', 'type': 'uint256'}], 'name': 'approve', 'outputs': [{'internalType': 'bool', 'name': '', 'type': 'bool'}], 'stateMutability': 'nonpayable', 'type': 'function'}, {'inputs': [{'internalType': 'address', 'name': 'account', 'type': 'address'}], 'name': 'balanceOf', 'outputs': [{'internalType': 'uint256', 'name': '', 'type': 'uint256'}], 'stateMutability': 'view', 'type': 'function'}, {'inputs': [], 'name': 'decimals', 'outputs': [{'internalType': 'uint8', 'name': '', 'type': 'uint8'}], 'stateMutability': 'pure', 'type': 'function'}, {'inputs': [{'internalType': 'address[]', 'name': 'notbot', 'type': 'address[]'}], 'name': 'delBots', 'outputs': [], 'stateMutability': 'nonpayable', 'type': 'function'}, {'inputs': [{'internalType': 'address', 'name': 'a', 'type': 'address'}], 'name': 'isBot', 'outputs': [{'internalType': 'bool', 'name': '', 'type': 'bool'}], 'stateMutability': 'view', 'type': 'function'}, {'inputs': [], 'name': 'manualSwap', 'outputs': [], 'stateMutability': 'nonpayable', 'type': 'function'}, {'inputs': [], 'name': 'manualsend', 'outputs': [], 'stateMutability': 'nonpayable', 'type': 'function'}, {'inputs': [], 'name': 'name', 'outputs': [{'internalType': 'string', 'name': '', 'type': 'string'}], 'stateMutability': 'pure', 'type': 'function'}, {'inputs': [], 'name': 'openTrading', 'outputs': [], 'stateMutability': 'nonpayable', 'type': 'function'}, {'inputs': [], 'name': 'owner', 'outputs': [{'internalType': 'address', 'name': '', 'type': 'address'}], 'stateMutability': 'view', 'type': 'function'}, {'inputs': [{'internalType': 'uint256', 'name': '_newFee', 'type': 'uint256'}], 'name': 'reduceFee', 'outputs': [], 'stateMutability': 'nonpayable', 'type': 'function'}, {'inputs': [], 'name': 'removeLimits', 'outputs': [], 'stateMutability': 'nonpayable', 'type': 'function'}, {'inputs': [], 'name': 'renounceOwnership', 'outputs': [], 'stateMutability': 'nonpayable', 'type': 'function'}, {'inputs': [], 'name': 'symbol', 'outputs': [{'internalType': 'string', 'name': '', 'type': 'string'}], 'stateMutability': 'pure', 'type': 'function'}, {'inputs': [], 'name': 'totalSupply', 'outputs': [{'internalType': 'uint256', 'name': '', 'type': 'uint256'}], 'stateMutability': 'pure', 'type': 'function'}, {'inputs': [{'internalType': 'address', 'name': 'recipient', 'type': 'address'}, {'internalType': 'uint256', 'name': 'amount', 'type': 'uint256'}], 'name': 'transfer', 'outputs': [{'internalType': 'bool', 'name': '', 'type': 'bool'}], 'stateMutability': 'nonpayable', 'type': 'function'}, {'inputs': [{'internalType': 'address', 'name': 'sender', 'type': 'address'}, {'internalType': 'address', 'name': 'recipient', 'type': 'address'}, {'internalType': 'uint256', 'name': 'amount', 'type': 'uint256'}], 'name': 'transferFrom', 'outputs': [{'internalType': 'bool', 'name': '', 'type': 'bool'}], 'stateMutability': 'nonpayable', 'type': 'function'}, {'stateMutability': 'payable', 'type': 'receive'}]

If anyone can help me decode this so I can extract the data from the transaction I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

You can use this function.
